# How to do back button that go back to previous layout?

Tags: java, android

i am new in android .. I want to ask question about Link 2 layouts using buttons. I have 2 xml layout and first layout can link to 2nd layout but 2nd layout can't go back to 1st layout. Please help me.

below are my codes...

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:text="Link to page 1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**page1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Page 1 test"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back to main page" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.linktest2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);




    btn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();

            myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

               myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            setContentView(R.layout.page1);

        }
    });

  }}
```

**page1.java**

```
package com.example.linktest2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class page1 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page1);

    Button btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);




    btn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();

            myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }
    });
```

}}

Comment: I think you are confuse with Acitvity and Xml ..

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong.

To go from MainActivity to page1 (by convention it should be Page1), you should start a new Activity (instead of changing the contentview of the current activity). Then to go back from Page1 to MainActivity, you can programmatically finish() the Activity, or the user can touch Back.

Answer (score 1):

You can either **keep your both layout in same layout file and make the show or hide the layout** accordingly.

Also another way is you can create two activity which contains two separate layout and load a second layout on click of button using intent and start activity as below

To Go to other activity you can do like this :

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally android deals with that itself.
However you can override OnBackPressed in your second activity and launch an intent that leads to your first activity

Going to other activity you can do like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

For each XML you need to have another Activity.

Answer (score 0):

In Main Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      Button btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),page1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();



            }
        });

}
```

Replace this

And in your Page1 Activity replace this

```
        public class page1 extends Activity {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page);

    Button btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    }); 
     }
               }
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to come back to activity A from activity B with some result,you can use like this
 activity B

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

activity A

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
            }
        }
}
```